# How does my Wi-Fi router seemingly cause lag in another hop?

Tags: router, routing, wireless-router, traceroute

```
$ traceroute -I 203.195.123.148
traceroute to 203.195.123.148 (203.195.123.148), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  2.249 ms  1.187 ms  1.257 ms
    ...
 8  180.87.67.46 (180.87.67.46)  42.661 ms  53.478 ms  42.304 ms
 9  82.128-240-180.static.telin.sg (180.240.128.82)  47.088 ms  45.556 ms  45.246 ms
10  188.42.201.243 (188.42.201.243)  46.873 ms  53.112 ms  47.859 ms
11  188.42.201.3 (188.42.201.3)  46.001 ms  46.489 ms  47.864 ms
12  203.195.123.148 (203.195.123.148)  229.291 ms  297.407 ms  307.287 ms
```

---

```
$ traceroute -I 203.195.123.148
traceroute to 203.195.123.148 (203.195.123.148), 64 hops max, 72 byte packets
    ...
 7  180.87.67.46 (180.87.67.46)  41.017 ms  40.599 ms  40.889 ms
 8  82.128-240-180.static.telin.sg (180.240.128.82)  41.230 ms  41.232 ms  41.056 ms
 9  188.42.201.245 (188.42.201.245)  41.757 ms  41.439 ms  41.713 ms
10  188.42.201.3 (188.42.201.3)  42.223 ms  41.703 ms  42.934 ms
11  203.195.123.148 (203.195.123.148)  80.122 ms  80.107 ms  80.534 ms
```

First traceroute is with a connection via my Wi-Fi router and second without router. Although the 2nd hop with my router and 1st hop without my router are different, from there everything is the exact same (I've removed some of the initial IP addresses but you can see the IP addresses 8-12 in #1 and 7-11 in #2 are exact same) -- what I don't understand is the mysterious lag at the last hop.

How is it that when I'm connected via a Wi-Fi router, the last hop consistently take so much time vs when I'm connected directly, the last hop still takes time but is now not so bad (again, consistently)?

Comment: Reposting from https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/69611/70425

Comment: Does the same thing happen if the router is in place but you connect to it via Ethernet not Wi-Fi? Do you have a simultaneous packet capture from both sides of the router? My first hunch is your router is doing NAT and some interaction between NAT and the last hop is causing some extra processing delay of the ICMP messages coming back from that last hop.

Comment: > Does the same thing happen if the router is in place but you connect to it via Ethernet not Wi-Fi?

Yes.

Didn't really follow rest of your comment (sorry, total noob in networking).

Comment: what do you mean by "connected directly"? (using the internet you are always connect to a router, otherwise IP wouldn't work)

Comment: @Albin If you only want one device connected, you can connect it directly to a plain modem that has no router functionality. So you don't need a *home* router.

Comment: @avamsi Sorry for the jargon. The issue you've noticed is definitely uncommon, so there's no easy answer. Figuring it out would require using a "packet sniffer" (a.k.a. "packet capture tool", "traffic analyzer", etc.) tool like tcpdump or Wireshark that can capture all the traffic on your Internet connection, and then someone with a deep understanding of network protocols would need to pore through the captured data to figure out what's going on. Capturing network traffic well is tricky, and figuring out what happened is often even more difficult.

Comment: @Spiff ok, you are right, you don't need NAT and you don't need a router as a device in your home (but you still need to connect to a router... but again in essence you are right I'm splitting hairs here... ;) but it would might be helpfull to know what exactly the OP means by connecting "directly" (DHCP, PPPoE, etc.)

Comment: @Albin, I get an ethernet cable from my ISP -- when I said directly, I meant using my laptop with said cable and go through a captive portal -- at which I can access the internet (this is traceroute #2 above). #1 is with a home router with connection type set to PPPoE (with the same credentials that I use on the captive portal).

Comment: @avamsi What is the cable connected to? A dsl-modem? Something else? A captive portal is unusual for for wired connections. What happens when you connect "the cable" directly to your laptop? Did you have to setup a PPPoE connection as well or does your laptop get an IP from a DHCP?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the cable is connected to on the other end, sorry :/ Now that I recently authenticated, I don't need to do anything extra (if not, I'd get redirected to the captive portal (when I try to open some webpage) and I would need to enter my credentials) -- my laptop gets assigned an IP (static, if that matters). While checking this, I just ran ping from my laptop connected "directly" and the sweet 80ms (from #2) turned to 200+ (like #1, till the last hop everything looks fine but last hop is so slow) -- so maybe router was never an issue? I don't know what's happening 

Comment: @avamsi well if you follow the cable from your laptop to the other end, how far can you go? why do you have to stop (why can't you see what it's connected to)? How does you laptop get assiged a static IP? Did you install some software or did you do it yourself? But I think you mean a dynamic IP through a DCHP server (although it's always the same it's still called dynamic). What are your IP settings? Please run cmd.exe and do `ipconfig /all` what's the result?

Comment: I'll hit a wall :) I think the cable comes from some space that my ISP rented in our apartment complex but I have no clue what goes on in there :/ (sorry, I know I sound dumb, but :shrugs:). Re: static, I knew you'd say that! Yeah, I guess it's still dynamic but IP is always the same. I'm on macOS -- would ifconfig give you the information you're looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112034/discussion-between-albin-and-avamsi).

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comments, Albin and Spiff -- my ISP refreshed my dynamic (but "constant") IP and am back to < 50ms ping (so nothing I posted so far is reproducible now :shrugs:).

Comment: @avamsi who is your ISP? if you don't mind me asking?! You might want to write an answer you can accept, or I can add the solution to my answer if you like (I don't mind the extra reputation)...

Comment: @Albin, accepted your answer :) https://www.actcorp.in is my ISP.

Comment: @avamsi Thanks, which IP was resetted? The public, the private or both?

Comment: IP that was assigned to me. It's public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are connected to some kind of "not so common" solution - at least not to me. A captive portal is usually used for open WLAN connections (hot spots). But there seem to be "PPPoE hotspots" out there, I just never encountered one myself. So thre will be the appropriate HW/SW (switch, PPPoE server, hotspot-server, etc. including a router ;) in the rented space you are connecting to.

But to answer your question, since you got the late link connecting directly as well, it's very unlikely that it is your WLAN-router's fault.

Update: the solution in the end was to let the ISP delete the IP lease so a new IP gets assigned.